# Why is my Submit using POST api call not working in this react front end?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, rest, react-fullstack

This is what my UI looks like

[enter image description here][1]

Clicking the save button should add a record to the database and it must show it in the below list. But it is not working. I even tested the post call using postman and it worked fine. Does it have something to do with react version? Also, the delete operation works fine.

Here is the console log. [enter image description here][2]

This is my component

````
import AppNav from './AppNav';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';

import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import { Table, FormGroup, Button, Input, Container, Label, Form } from 'reactstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Category from './Category';
import Moment from 'react-moment';

class Expenses extends Component {

    emptyItem = {
        description : '' ,
        expensedate : new Date(),
        id:104,
        location : '',
        category : {id:1 , name:'Travel'}
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            isLoading: false,
            Categories : [],
            Expenses : [],
            date : new Date(),
            item : this.emptyItem
        }
        this.handleSubmit= this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleChange= this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleDateChange= this.handleDateChange.bind(this);
    }

    async handleSubmit(event) {

        const item = this.state.item;


        await fetch(`/api/expenses`, {
            method : 'POST',
            headers : {
                'Accept' : 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            },
            body : JSON.stringify(item),
        });

        //console.log(this.state);
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.history.push("/expenses");
    }

    handleChange(event){
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.value;
        const name = target.name;
        let item={...this.state.item};
        item[name] = value;
        this.setState({item});
        console.log(item);
    }

    handleDateChange(date){
        let item={...this.state.item};
        item.expensedate= date;
        this.setState({item});
        //console.log(item);
      }


    async remove(id){
        await fetch(`/api/expenses/${id}` , {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'Accept' : 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(() => {
            let updatedExpenses = [...this.state.Expenses].filter(i => i.id !== id);
            this.setState({Expenses : updatedExpenses});
        });
    }


    async componentDidMount() {

        const response = await fetch('/api/categories');
        const body = await response.json();
        this.setState({Categories : body , isLoading : false});

        const responseExp = await fetch('/api/expenses');
        const bodyExp = await responseExp.json();
        this.setState({Expenses : bodyExp , isLoading : false});        
    }


    render() {
        const title= <h3>Add Expense</h3>;
        const {Categories} = this.state;
        const {Expenses, isLoading} = this.state;

        if(isLoading)
            return(<div>Loading....</div>)

            let optionList = 
                Categories.map( category =>
                    <option value={category.id} key={category.id}>
                        {category.name}
                        </option>
                )
            
            let rows=
                Expenses.map( expense =>
                    <tr key={expense.id}>
                        <td>{expense.description}</td>
                        <td>{expense.location}</td>
                        <td><Moment date={expense.expensedate} format="YYYY/MM/DD"/></td>
                        <td>{expense.category.name}</td>
                        <td><Button size="sm" color="danger" onClick={() => this.remove(expense.id)}>Delete</Button></td>
                    </tr>
                    )

        return ( 
            <div>
                <AppNav/>
                <Container>
                    {title}
                    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label for="description">Title</Label>
                            <Input type="description" name="description" id="description" 
                                onChange={this.handleChange} autoComplete="name"/>
                        </FormGroup>

                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label for="category" >Category</Label>
                            <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
                                    {optionList}
                            </select>
                        </FormGroup>

                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label for="city">Date</Label>
                            <DatePicker selected={this.state.item.expensedate} onChange={this.handleDateChange}/>
                        </FormGroup>
                        
                        <div className="row">
                        <FormGroup className="col-md-4 mb-3">
                            <Label for="location">Location</Label>
                            <input type="text" name="location" id="location" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                        </FormGroup>
                        </div>

                        <FormGroup>
                            <Button color="primary" type="subimt">Save</Button>{' '}
                            <Button color="secondary" tag={Link} to="/">Cancel</Button>
                        </FormGroup>
                    </Form>
                </Container>

            {''}
                <Container>
                    <h3>Expense List</h3>
                    <Table className="mt-4">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th width="30%">Description</th>
                                <th width="10%">Location</th>
                                <th>Date</th>                                
                                <th>Category</th>
                                <th width="10%">Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {rows}
                        </tbody>

                    </Table>
                </Container>

            </div>
         );
    }
}
 
export default Expenses;```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1wqk.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwOVQ.png
````

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Please add specifics about the error - the nature of it, errors codes/messages, etc.

Comment: I've explained everything in the first few lines of description. Please check